# Xcode: Creating Class Function Definitions in .cpp from Function prototypes in .h

Tags: c++, xcode, function, command, member

I am almost positive there is a very nifty shortcut/command in Xcode where you can quickly and seamlessly create empty formatted function definitions in a project's .cpp file from the class function prototypes in the project's .h file. I know this is a feature in visual and i am 95% sure its a feature in Xcode. Anyone got any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: I've used Xcode for three years now, and if such a feature exists for C++, i've not seen it. Objetive-C *maybe*.

Comment: It's not a feature of C++ its a feature of the IDE itself. Maybe i'm wrong about Xcode but i know it exists in visual.  My professor demonstrated it for my class the other day. It's just a command that allows easy implementation of your function prototypes into their source file format.  They are blank but then all you have to do is define them instead of writing out all the formatting.  Its just a simple tool to save time.

Comment: I'm fully aware it would be a feature of the IDE. And I've used it extensively in Visual Studio, so I know the feature you speak of. I've simply not seen it in Xcode (for C++ anyway, there is something *similar*, but not really the same, for Objective-C).

Comment: Gotchya! Thanks man i must be mistaken then :(... such a nice feature too!

Answer (score 0):

To use function definition feature like in Visual Studio, use Refactor->Create Missing Function Definitions.[image]

Result:

[image]